# Use getters/setters in Svelte Custom methods

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am not able to compile my svelte component when using a get/set pair in custom methods. Is this not supported? Or am I doing something wrong?

Example:

Say I wanted to have a component that displays a name and I want to set the name using.

`com.name = 'The new name';`

However I only want the component to use the name if it has no spaces in the name.

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                name: 'The Name',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            get displayName() {
                return this.get('name'); 
            },
            set displayName(val) {
                if (val.indexOf(' ') < 0) {
                    this.set('name', val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The Issue is that when I try to compile this, it says there is a duplicate key.

```
    Duplicate property 'displayName'

    49:             return this.get('name');
    50:         },
    51:         set displayName(val) {
```

Here is a REPL - https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.13.2&gist=0eeab5717526694139ba73eae766bb30

I don't see anything in the documentation about this. I can just not use setters, but I would like to be able to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr this is possible with a [wrapper object](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/svelte-accessors-demo)**

The error message here is a bit confusing — it's not the duplicate property that's a problem, is that you can't have getters and setters in `methods`, which in any case is separate from the `data` object that populates a component's internal state (along with data supplied at instantiation and any computed values there might be). I've opened an issue for that [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/425).

The `data` itself also can't have getters and setters — or rather it can, but they won't be used, because the object returned from your `data` function isn't the same as the internal state object (otherwise we'd all probably run into mutation-related bugs).

But it's actually fairly easy to create a wrapper object that allows you to get and set a component's data:

```js
function wrap (component) {
  var wrapper = {};
  var data = component.get();

  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    Object.defineProperty(wrapper, key, {
      get() {
        return component.get()[key];
      },
      set(value) {
        component.set({ obj[key]: value });
      }
    })
  });

  return wrapper;
}

var component = new Component({...});
var wrapper = wrap(component);

wrapper.name = 'Rich';
```

You could even do `component.data = wrap(component)` if you were so inclined — then you could manipulate `component.data.name` and so on.

I've put together a [small repo](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/svelte-accessors-demo) demoing that approach — [see it in action here](https://svelte-accessors-cmpbzhrlcp.now.sh/).

Comment: I was very mislead by the error. Thanks for coming up with this solution, I think it will come in handy!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As Rich Harris pointed out in the comments below, getters and setters won't work within `data` because Svelte copies the properties to a plain JS object internally (thus ignoring getters and setters). I think the next best thing you can do is make a method `name` that can be called like `name()` as a getter, and `name(value)` as a setter.

### Svelte Code:

```
<h1>Hello {{_name}}!</h1>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        _name: 'The Name'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      name(value) {
        if (value === void 0) return this.get('_name')
        this.set('_name', value)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

**Original Post:**

Your getter and setter should be in your `data` rather than your `methods`, because they create a property in the end. This property conflicts with the `name` you defined as equal to `'The Name'` inside your original `data` method. I would suggest using a "private" property `_name` instead.

### Svelte Code ([REPL](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.13.2&gist=e4268734b93ed8ff26272a8706bb0b2c)):

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        _name: 'The Name',
        get name() {
          return this._name
        },
        set name(value) {
          / /.test(this._name) || (this._name = value)
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It is still an issue event if you change the property name in the data section. It seems like it is conflicting with the getter. I changed the `name` in data to `displayName`. The same issue arises.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't move the getter and setter away from `methods` and into `data`. Try doing that, and let me know what happens.

Comment: Using accessors in the `data` function won't work, because the state object that Svelte components use internally are POJOs generated by combining the return value of the `data` function, any `data` supplied at instantiation, and a component's computed values (if it has any). In other words, the accessor will only be used once, at instantiation, then ignored.

Comment: Oh, yuck. That's unfortunate. Thank you for enlightening me about Svelte's internals. I guess OP will, unfortunately, have to use another approach.

Comment: @RichHarris So I suppose a get function is not needed since you can use `.get('name')` on the component. Would making a `setName` custom method be the way to go?

Comment: @Zac Just edited the post with an alternative. Let me know what you think; I think this is your next best option though it is hardly ideal.

Comment: @gyre I believe that in the methods section you would need to use `this.set('_name', value);`

Comment: This would also not be the same as a get/set property. A set would look like `com.name('new name')`, not `com.name = 'new name'`.
Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think accessors will work based on what Rich Harris mentioned earlier. I thought this would be the second-best bet.

Comment: I have a solution involving a wrapper object — will post a new answer in a moment. Demo here: https://svelte-accessors-cmpbzhrlcp.now.sh/

Comment: Impressive! Hopefully that will work and I can delete this post.

Comment: Thank you for investigating and prompting me to think about how to make this work! :)